# Jedi Illusions in Legends

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force, jedi

I remember projecting large scale illusions being a Sith magic thing in legends.

Is there any evidence of this being done by as a light side power by Jedi in particular, or at least some other light side force user in the old legends continuity?

Inspired by end of the The Last Jedi where:

> Luke creates an illusion of himself to distract the first order

Comment: I would consider any force ghost as being a force projection / illusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a trick appears several times in legends.

The Star Wars wiki lists this force power under [Dopplegänger](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Doppleg%C3%A4nger):

> **Dopplegänger**, or **Similfuturus**, was a Force power that allowed a user to create a perfect illusion of him- or herself through the Force. The ability could also be used to duplicate objects that were visually indistinguishable from the real item.